# PyQt: Getting the amount of lines from QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to make a chat application, so i added the QTextEdit widget where user types the content, maximum height of widget is **30** pixels, so basically **one** line.

```
    self.msgtext = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
    self.msgtext.setObjectName('msgtext')
    self.msgtext.setStyleSheet("#msgtext {background-color: black; color: yellow; font-size: 18pt; }")
    self.msgtext.setMaximumSize(500, 30)
    self.msgtextplain = self.msgtext.toPlainText()
```

I want to increase the maximum height of the widget whenever user get's one new line, But i don't know if there is any signal that can tell that i have reached new line.

Is there any signal, that can count the amount of lines from QTextEdit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `blockCount()` but don't forget to also resize whatever parent you are using for your `QTextEdit`. Here is an example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.msgtext = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.msgtext.setObjectName('msgtext')
        self.msgtext.setStyleSheet("#msgtext {background-color: black; color: yellow; font-size: 18pt; }")
        self.msgtext.resize(500, 30)
        self.msgtextplain = self.msgtext.toPlainText()

        self.msgtext.textChanged.connect(self.changed)

    def changed(self):
        lines = self.msgtext.document().blockCount()
        self.msgtext.resize(500, 30*lines)
        self.resize(500, 30*lines)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It's <kbd>PyQt5</kbd>. To do this in <kbd>PyQt4</kbd> change everything that is `QtWidgets` to `QtGui` (and check the import lines evidently; this should be enough but do tell if you have any difficulties). Here is the result:

[image: Dynamically resizing a QLineEdit]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the awesome and detailed answer!, worked without any problems!